# Why do unfinished wooden utensils have a different law than unfinished metal utensils?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, maseches-keilim, metals, utensil

In [Keilim 12:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kelim.12.8?lang=bi), we see that unfinished wooden utensils with a receptacle are susceptible to *tumah*, except those woods whose properties make the utensil unusable.

> ‮... כל גולמי כלי עץ טמאין, חוץ משל אשכרוע. רבי יהודה אומר, אף גרופייות של זית, טהורה, עד שתישלק.
>
> ... All unfinished wooden vessels also are susceptible to impurity, excepting those made of boxwood. Rabbi Judah says: one made of an olive-tree branch is also clean unless it was first heated.

However, in [Keilim 12:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kelim.12.6?lang=bi), we have a disagreement as to whether unfinished metal utensils are susceptible to *tumah*.

> ‮ארבעה דברים רבן גמליאל מטמא, וחכמים מטהרין... וגולמי כלי מתכות...
>
> There are four things which Rabban Gamliel says are susceptible to impurity, and the sages say are not susceptible to impurity: ... and metal vessels which are still unfinished ...

Although Rabban Gamliel's opinion in 12:6 works well with 12:8, the sages' opinion does not. What are ways that commentators have tried to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

This question is asked and answered in the Gemara in [Hulin 25a-b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chullin.25b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he). A Sefaria explains:

> מאי שנא הני ומאי שנא הני?‏
>  רבי יוחנן אמר "הואיל ולכבוד עשויין"‏
>  רב נחמן אמר "הואיל ודמיהן יקרים"‏

The Gemara asks: What is different about these unfinished **wooden vessels** , with regard to which the halakha is that **provided they are fit for use they are susceptible to impurity**, and what is different about those unfinished **metal vessels**, with regard to which the halakha is that **even if they are fit for use they are not susceptible to impurity until their crafting is complete**?

Rabbi Yoḥanan answers: The difference is that since **metal vessels are crafted for uses of honor**, they are not considered vessels until their completion.

Rav Naḥman answers: The difference is that since the worth of **metal vessels is expensive, they cannot be sold at that price unless they are complete**.